# How do I flash a bootloader onto a Cortex-M0 with hobby-priced hardware?

Tags: atmel, cortex-m0, samd21

I was working on a schematic based around the ATmega32U4, but those are on backorder until 2023!! I was looking for alternatives and saw that a lot of Adafruit's hobby kits have switched from AVR to the SAM D21 family. It's very compelling (especially the integration with Make Code).

But, I'm looking for how you get a UF2 bootloader onto the uC, and it appears your options are pretty limited (and often either really expensive or unavailable).

I found this [IBDAP](https://ibdap.net/) programmer. Does it work? Are there better/other options? What has your experience been with bare SAM D21s?

I also saw that some people were working with the [ST-LINK/V2](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html) with some success; however, the default ST-LINK firmware has an issue with the word size when writing.  So, some people were able to use one ST-LINK to flash a second ST-LINK with a firmware that does successfully flash SAM D21s.

I reviewed other answers and they mostly centered around either one of the more expensive JTAG devices or having the manufacturer flash the bootloader onto the uC with a minimum batch size of roughly 100 units or so (I just need . . . maybe 20?)

I looked around to see if anyone sold these with the UF2 already flashed on them but I didn't see evidence of that.

What do hobbyists usually do to get a bootloader onto the SAMD21?

Comment: Atmel/Microchip xplain boards have a debugger/programmer, cheapy Segger clones or NXP lpc-link with open source firmware.

Comment: @Kartman I saw that the xplained kit has the embedded debugger that allows you to debug and flash the on-board M0, but I wasn't able to find documentation that you could use it to flash external devices.  Have you seen it done?

Comment: It can be done but they don’t make it easy. The xplained  board is probably not the best solution. Lpc-link2 with cmsis-dap firmware seems to be a cheap solution. I’ve not tried it with a samd21.

Comment: I think PicKit4 has support for most (all?) SAMD processors. PicKit4 is pretty cheap. Or the MPLAB SNAP, pretty much the same thing but even cheaper with no enclosure.

Comment: I'll bet that PicKit4 is exactly what I need!  I can't believe how many different searches I did to try to find that exact thing and it never came up.